# Как выяснить все возможные роуты у сайта или веб приложения?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, веб-интерфейс

Разработчик скрыл кнопку для внешнего пользователя, которая ведет на определенную страницу. Если известно, что страница точно существует, как найти или просмотреть список возможных роутов, чтоб вручную ввести в адресной строке путь к нужной странице (разделу сайта)?

Comment: Посмотреть где? В общем случае нет никакого списка «роутов»

Comment: Возможно есть какие-то инструменты веб-разработчика для анализа веб-ресурсов. Я поэтому и спрашиваю, возможно они есть, а я не знаю.

Comment: Никакой инструмент не сможет найти страницу, информация о которой нигде не показывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть всякие дополнительные интрсументы, которые с помощью анализа фронтенда пытаются выяснить существующие роуты, например на [этом сайте](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) просто введите ссылку и он покажет все роуты

Comment: Нет никакой гарантии, что он покажет **все** роуты

Comment: Конечно да, это просто попытка узнать хоть какие то роуты
Даже фронтендер не всега может знать списко всех роутов у сервиса для бэка, который он использует